# SQLite 3 copy data from old table into new table

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables with identical structure which I need to copy several columns from one to the other.  Something like this:

*** UPDATE ****

Apparently I need to update the new table.  I want to copy the data from the old table into the new table for each record that the name matches.  I'm not sure what command to use.  Here is an approximation:

```
copy from OLDTABLE columns category, key into NEWTABLE when the names match
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not have proper syntax.  It has two select clauses, the second of which does not have a from:

```
insert into newdata
    select category, key
    from olddata
    select category, key
    where olddata.name = newdata.name
```

I am guessing that you want something like:

```
insert into newdata(cateogry, key)
    select olddata.category, olddata.key
    from olddata 
    where olddata.name
```

Do you really want an insert, or are you looking for an update?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're right, I need to update, not insert. I'm confusing the commands.